# I am trying to run this code in code::blocks and it's showing a an error like undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'. Can anyone help me fix the problem?

Tags: c, windows, unicode

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR szCmdLine, int CmdShow)
{
    MessageBoxW(NULL,szCmdLine, L"Title", MB_OK);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear: You need a `WinMain` function. You provide a `wWinMain` function.

Comment: Please do not put the whole question in the title. Then you have some text left for the body.

Comment: You should post more illustrative code, as the current code can run in the compiler.

Comment: @StriveSun: I've seen wWinMain fail to resolve before when WinMain would resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're using Visual Studio. In project properties, under General, check Character Set. It should be Unicode.

With Unicode, the toolchain assumes your entry point is `wWinMain`, with multibyte it assumes `WinMain`.